Code for a button in power apps with required fields -- email and password
I'm currently creating a daily mobile time tracker of employees, I would like to ask for help on what should I code in the button to proceed with the next screen after login. However, the required fields such as email and password must be provided by the user. If either of the two was not met, if the user click the button, it will not proceed.
Thanks.

There are different ways that is can be done, here are a couple of examples:

Change the DisplayMode property of the button
If(
IsBlank(inpEmail.Text) ||
IsBlank(inpPass.Text),
DisplayMode.View,
DisplayMode.Edit
)

Display notification when the button is clicked when e-mail/password inputs are blank
If(
IsBlank(inpEmail.Text) ||
IsBlank(inpPass.Text),
Notify( "Email and/or Pass required", NotificationType.Error ),
Navigate("Next Screen")
)



I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved.
